# PHP Regular Expression: Get numbers between underscore

Tags: php, regex

I have an issue with a regular expression which just doesn't seem to work out the way I want.

Here are two examples of (different) input strings:

- 1111_market1233_**700x100**_BLU
- 1111_market232_**8000x000**_AES
- 1111_market11_**689x41777**_CER

Of course, not having the best knowledge of regular expressions, I fail to get the bold parts of the text for different reasons. Below is my example of doing it:

```
preg_match("/_([^0-9])x([^0-9])_/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Of course, this is not working. The expected output I want is:

- 700x100
- 8000x000
- 689x41777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Just add repetition and remove `^`:

```
/_([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)_/
```

`^` within a character set makes the set match anything **but** what is inside. Aka `[^0-9]` would match anything that is not a digit.

Also character sets by themselves match only one character. Aka `[0-9]` matches just one digit. `+` means *match 1 or more times*.

---

If you want to remove the underscores from the match, you would use [positive lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It will make the regex just verify they are there, instead of including them in the match:

```
/(?<=_)([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)(?=_)/
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/vQ2jU9/2)

Comment: Quick!!! Thanks. Can you try remove the underscores as well? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/chF

Comment: You rock. I will accept this answer in 5 minutes, can't do it yet... Thanks a lot buddy. Really appreciated!!!